# Image field: mark an image as a "cover photo" with a radio button

Tags: flags, media

In a given content type, I have three **Image** fields, each of them set to **Unlimited** cardinality. It's like a little **gallery** with 3 fixed **albums**: when using Display Suite, I have the ability to limit the number of values getting displayed, I limited it to 1:
[image: Image - Display Suite, gallery]
and this way **only the first image gets displayed**. The fields link to a page created by Views, which shows the images separately as a gallery, etc...

Here's an example of the result:

[image: Gallery, 3 albums]

What I would like to achieve is to **provide a radio button near the images** to the user **when editing these fields** to be able to **select** which image I would like to **show as a "cover photo"** **without reordering the images**. In the example above, I can only show the 1st one in the "album".

Do you have any ideas for that? Is there a module for this task, or do I have to code?
Can I solve this problem without converting my solution to other gallery solutions? I was thinking about [Flag](https://drupal.org/project/flag) module, but I couldn't find out how I could use it for this task. I'm using [File entity (fieldable files)](https://drupal.org/project/file_entity) module, which may help in solving this question.

Answer (score 4):

One approach would be to use [file entity](https://drupal.org/project/file_entity) and add a field to the image file entity, but that would require re-working your current solution quite a bit.

Another approach would be to use the

[Field Attach API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.attach.inc/group/field_attach/7)

e.g:

- [`field_attach_form`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.attach.inc/function/field_attach_form/7)
- [`field_attach_submit`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.attach.inc/function/field_attach_submit/7)

to attach the additional field to the image. The field would then need to be checked during output to show/hide that image as the cover image.

Update:

Here's an example to add a checkbox to an image field. I had some settings on the instance form to show/hide the extra fields, removed for conciseness here. You may be able to use hook_field_attach_form though I used a element process hook instead.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_element_info().
 */
function MODULE_element_info() {
  $extra = array(
    '#process' => array('MODULE_element_process'),
  );

  $elements = array();
  // Add our process function to all managed_file elements
  $elements['managed_file'] = $extra;

  return $elements;
}

/**
 * An additional preprocess callback to append the form.
 */
function MODULE_element_process($element, $form_state, $complete_form) {

  if (!isset($element['#entity_type']) || !isset($element['#field_name'])) {
    return $element;
  }

  // You can get the field data, settings etc.. like this
  $item = $element['#value'];
  $field = field_info_field($element['#field_name']);
  $instance = field_info_instance($element['#entity_type'], $element['#field_name'], $element['#bundle']);
  $settings = $instance['settings'];
  $widget_type = $instance['widget']['type'];

  // Add element, only if file id available
  if ($element['fid']['#value']) {
    // Note default value selects from cache / db table TABLE_file_data
    $element['cover'] = array(
     '#type' => 'checkbox',
     '#title' => t('Cover'),
     '#default_value' => MODULE_file_data_value($element['fid']['#value'], 'cover', '')
    );
  }

  return $element;

}

/**
 * Implements hook_field_attach_presave
 *
 * Saves a files additional field data.
 */
function MODULE_field_attach_presave($entity_type, $entity) {
  list($id, $vid, $bundle) = entity_extract_ids($entity_type, $entity);
  $supported_widgets = array('image_image', 'imagefield_crop_widget');
  $instances = field_info_instances($entity_type, $bundle);
  foreach ($instances as $field_name => $instance) {
    if (in_array($instance['widget']['type'], $supported_widgets)) {

      $settings = $instance['settings'];
      // I have some settings I check as well, if enabled on field instance..
      //if (empty($settings['display_cover'])){
      //  continue;
      //}
      // Find all of the field items.
      $items = field_get_items($entity_type, $entity, $instance['field_name']);

      if (is_array($items)) {
        // Loop over and save extended field values
        foreach ($items as $delta => $item) {
          $fields = array();
          if (!empty($item['fid'])) {
            if(isset($item['cover'])){
              $fields['cover'] = $item['cover'];
            }
            $fields['changed'] = REQUEST_TIME;
            db_merge('TABLE_file_data')
              ->key(array('fid' => $item['fid']))
              ->fields($fields)->execute();
            // Need to clear entity cache for this file
            // as update was not with api but direct query
            cache_clear_all($item['fid'], 'cache_entity_file');
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: +1, thanks for your answer, David! _"use file entity and add a field to the image file entity, but that would require re-working your current solution quite a bit."_ This sounds good, I'm already using this module. I thought about using Flag module, and adding this to the file entity, but couldn't work out the how-to yet (maybe it's not the best solution). Reworking? How? I don't really know Field Attach API, but I'm open to this idea too. Could you show me a little example how it would look like? Or if you have more ideas, please share them. I'm starting a bounty as a motivation :)

Comment: David, could you provide any additional information regarding using Field Attach API? :) I haven't found out how I could use it for the given task, but I'm really curious. Or adding a field to file entity also seems like a good idea, but it should behave as a conditional field which operates only when used for given Image fields. Thanks for any ideas in advance!

Comment: @Sk8erPeter code example added, cheers.

Comment: David, thanks for your code! 1st of all, I was a fool, I wrote "checkbox" instead of "radio button". :(( With a **radio button** using the same `name` attr., only one option could be selected, and that's the main task. I'm really sorry for this mistake. If `'#type' => 'radio'` is used, should `#name` be used? Some more questions before acceptance: 1. Why not using `hook_element_info_alter()` instead? 2. Could you show me a small example of `MODULE_file_data_value()` function too? 3. You used `TABLE_file_data` - so should an own table be defined via `hook_schema`?Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: OK, here's what I did: I created a simple custom table with `hook_schema` with `field_name` and `fid` fields (OK, cool, not too complicated), changed the `$element['cover']` field element's properties in `MODULE_element_process()` to `'#type' => 'radio', '#parents' => array($field_name, 'cover'), '#return_value' => $element['#value']['fid'], '#default_value' => testmodule_get_image_field_cover($field_name),`, implemented the `testmodule_get_image_field_cover` with using a simple `db_select` query (storing the value in a static variable) - OK, radio buttons appear correctly, BUT... (cont'd...)

Comment: ... BUT the problem is that the shown `#parents` property changes the `$element['cover']` radio input field's `name` attribute to something like `field_test_image[cover]` for all the image fields (**this is OK**, because for allowing only one image to be selected, the same `name` attribute has to be used for the fields, otherwise multiple could be selected!), AND this way the `cover`'s fid value doesn't show up in `hook_field_attach_presave`. What would be the appropriate way to achieve this value in `hook_field_attach_presave` too?

Comment: Here's an example screenshot of the markup: http://i.imgur.com/KRzTJy9.png. Of course, `checked="checked"` gets added when one of these radio buttons get selected. BUT its value does not show up in `hook_field_attach_presave()`. So the main question is: how to achieve the checked `field_test_image[cover]` value (which will be an `fid`) in `MODULE_field_attach_presave()`?

Comment: sorry, should I start a bounty again? :D Or do you have any minor tips? Thanks in advance, and sorry for the tons of comments.

Comment: :-( OK, I think later I'll paste the complete code of the module I currently would like to develop further, upload it somewhere, shorten the question, and start a bounty again.